# how to move the rect transform by mouse drag

Tags: c#

I am trying to do a slider in the UI with the mouse, I want to move the rect transform right side when I drag the mouse right and vice-versa.

I tried but it didn't work please help me thanks in advance!!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using DG.Tweening;

public class slide : MonoBehaviour {

Vector3 prevpos = Vector3.zero;
Vector3 posdelta = Vector3.zero;

float xRotation = 0;
float zRotation = 0;
public RectTransform controllerposition;
public GameObject lastposition;



float speedFactor = 0.04f;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        prevpos = Input.mousePosition;
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {

        posdelta = Input.mousePosition - prevpos;


        Vector3.Distance(controllerposition.transform.position, lastposition.transform.position);
        {
            controllerposition.DOAnchorPos(new Vector2(-100, 0), 0.25f);

        }




    }

    prevpos = Input.mousePosition;
}


}
```

Comment: Please take the time to preview your question to ensure your code is formatted correctly, and consult the [help] if you need assistance formatting it correctly.

Comment: Why are there brackets around `controllerposition.DOAnchorPos(new Vector2(-100, 0), 0.25f);`?